# libpython3.6-dev, libpython3.6 and mysqlclient not installing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I tried installing mysql client using `pip install mysqlclient` but ended up as

```
#include "Python.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I tried installing packages that could detect header file `Python.h`
For that I tried `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`
But that resulted into

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.6-dev : Depends: python3.6 (= 3.6.6-1~18.04) but 3.6.6-1+xenial1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.6-dev (= 3.6.6-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.6 (= 3.6.6-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to deal with this situation and where the problem lies?

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: My python version is 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are having dependency issue. Install libpython3.6-dev then python3.6-dev and mysql. After that I hope you will be able to install mysqlclient.

```
sudo apt install libpython3.6-dev
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
sudo apt instal mysql-server
```

Then you will be able to install mysqlclient.

**if this does not happen it's good to uninstall and reinstall the python3.6 because many people got solution in this way. You can can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065888/impossible-to-install-with-apt-get-python-missing)

You may use following commands to do that and repeat those above commands.

```
sudo apt purge libpython3*
sudo apt-get purge python3.6
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install python3.6*
```

Hope it will sove your problem.

Comment: Yes, had to reinstall python packages. Thanks a lot for the solution.